# MS Access 2010 SQL Top N query by group performance issue (continued)

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access-2010

I have signficant performcance issues (up to time-out) in MS Access 2010 with the query below. The table TempTableAnalysis contains between 10'000-15'000 records. I have already received input from this forum to work with a temporary table in the top 10 query ([MS Access 2010 SQL Top N query by group performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717901/ms-access-2010-sql-top-n-query-by-group-performance-issue))

Can anyone explain how to implement the temporary table in the subquery and how to join it? I can't get it to work.

Any other suggestions to improve performance are highly appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
t2.Loc, 
t2.ABCByPick, 
t2.Planner, 
t2.DmdUnit, 
ROUND(t2.MASE,2) AS MASE, 
ROUND(t2.AFAR,2) AS AFAR

FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t2

WHERE t2.MASE IN  (
SELECT TOP 10 t1.MASE 
FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t1
WHERE t1.ABCByPick = t2.ABCByPick
ORDER BY t1.MASE DESC
)
ORDER BY
t2.ABCByPick, 
t2.MASE DESC;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your performance problems are probably coming from the fact that you are doing a select in your where clause. Each time you do a comparison you are doing a select as well. So if you have a 1000 rows, you are doing a thousand selects on top of the comparison. You should try refactor your query so you are using joins. If you can explain your problem and I can try help you a little more. The table names/columns are pretty confusing to figure out what you are doing.

Comment: From a first look, I can tell you that a SQL IN-List (i.e., the part that begins with: `WHERE t2.MASE IN ( SELECT TOP 10 t1.MASE FROM Temp...`) is usually interpreted as a very long string of SQL `OR`statements.  Even on an  Oracle database, IN-Lists with set sizes of more than a few thousand sometimes show performance problems.  If your inner-query (the IN-list set) is sufficiently large compared to your outermost set, a join is probably more suitable or at least worth a try.

Comment: Here an explanation of the fields: loc = warehouse, ABCByPick = attribute of the product, planner = person responsible for the product, dmdunit = partnumber of the product, MASE = quality factor of the product (AFAR is not relevant). The attribute ABCByPick can have values from A thru F. With a first query I want to get the top 10 MASE by ABCByPick. With a second query I would like to get the top 10 MASE by ABCByPick and by planner (i.e. planner 1 may have products with ABCByPick = A, B, C). I have not yet figured out how to do this with a join, since all data is in one table.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The solution I posted addresses the original query, which is just the `ABCByPick` problem.  You look like you're shaping a suite of query results that are actually pivots across different dimensions and grouping values.  See if you can solve the performance issues for one, and then move on to how you can supply your different variations.

Answer (score 2):

### Optimizing Access Query Performance For Large Data Sets

Based on your posted SQL Query, you have some options available to optimize and speed up the performance.

```
SELECT 
   t2.Loc, 
   t2.ABCByPick, 
   t2.Planner, 
   t2.DmdUnit, 
   ROUND(t2.MASE,2) AS MASE, 
   ROUND(t2.AFAR,2) AS AFAR

   FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t2
   ...
```

This is the first part where `TempTableAnalysis` is the multi-thousand record subquery.  If you want to squeeze a little more performance out of the use of this "Temp" Table, don't use it as a dynamic query (i.e., calculated on demand each time the query is opened), try constructing a macro that pushes the output to a static table:

**Appending Subquery Data to a Static Table:**

1. Create a `QUERY` object and change its type to `DELETE`.  Design it to delete the contents of your "temporary" table object.  If you prefer using SQL, the command will look like:

   ```
   DELETE My_Table.*
   FROM My_Table;
   ```
2. Create a `QUERY` object and change its type to `APPEND`.  Design it to query all fields from your query defined by the SQL statement of this OP.  Again, the SQL version of this task has the following syntax:

   ```
   INSERT INTO StaticAnalysisTable ( ID, Loc, Item, AvgOfScaledError )
   SELECT t1.ID, t1.Loc, t1.Item, t1.AvgOfScaledError
     FROM TempTableAnalysis as t1;
   ```

   The next step is to automate the population of this static table and it is optional.  It's simple however and will make it less likely that you will make the mistake of forgetting to "Refresh" and accessing your static table while it has stale data... causing inaccuracies in your results.
3. Create a macro with two steps.  Each step will have the following definition:  `OPEN QUERY`.  When prompted for the query to open, reference the objects you created in the previous two steps in the following order (important):  (1) `DELETE Query: (your delete query name)` then (2) `APPEND Query: (your append query name)`.

**SQL Query Comments and Suggestions**

The following part of the posted SQL query could use some help:

```
...

WHERE t2.MASE IN  (

     SELECT TOP 10 t1.MASE 
     FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t1
     WHERE t1.ABCByPick = t2.ABCByPick
     ORDER BY t1.MASE DESC
     )

ORDER BY
   t2.ABCByPick, 
   t2.MASE DESC;
```

1. There is a join across the sub query that generates the TOP-10 data and the outermost query that correlates these results with the supplementing `MASE` table data.  This isn't necessary if the `TempTableAnalysis.MASE` represents a key value.
2. `ORDER BY`

   in the inner most query isn't necessary unless it is intended to force some sort of selection criteria (as in when using SQL analytical functions)  this doesn't look like one of those cases.  Ordering records from large data sets is also a wasteful cpu and memory sink.

> **EDIT:**  Just as a counter-point argument, the `ORDER BY` clause used beside a TOP N query actually has a purpose, but I am still not clear if it is necessary.  Just to round out the discussion, another SO thread talks about [How to Select Top 10 in an Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247235/access-2010-sql-using-where-in-on-select-top-subquery-field).

3. `WHERE t2.MASE IN (...`

   You may be experiencing blocks in performance with very large in-list set operations.  On an Oracle database server, I have discovered with other developers that there is a limitation to the number of discrete elements in an in-list query operator.  That value was in the thousands... which may be further limited based on server and database resources.

   Consider using a SQL `JOIN` operator.  The place where you define `TABLE` objects can also be populated with SQL defined queries with aliases known as `INLINE VIEWS`.  Since you're using ACCESS, if an inline view does not work directly, just define another `ACCESS QUERY` object and reference it in your final query as if it were a table...

   A possible rewrite to the ending part of the original query:

   ```
   SELECT 
      t2.Loc, 
      t2.ABCByPick, 
      t2.Planner, 
      ...

   FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t2,
      (SELECT TOP 10 t1.MASE, t1.ABCByPick
         FROM TempTableAnalysis AS t1) AS ttop

   WHERE t2.MASE = ttop.MASE
     AND t2.ABCByPick = ttop.ABCByPick

   ORDER BY
      t2.ABCByPick, 
      t2.MASE DESC;
   ```

> You will definitely need to run through these recommendations and validate the output data for accuracy.  This represents approaches to capturing some of the "low-hanging fruit" (easy items) that you can pursue to speed up your query and reporting operations.

**Conclusions and Closing Comments**

As a background to other readers, the database object `TempTableAnalysis` is *not* a static table.  It is the result of a sub query presented in another SO post requesting help with a [Access TOP N Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717901/ms-access-2010-sql-top-n-query-by-group-performance-issue).  The query comes from multiple tables approaching 10,000 records in size (each?).

> **Tip:**  A query result in Access ALSO has potential table-like behaviors.  You can push the output to a table for joining (as described above) or just join to the query object itself (careful though, especially when you get to "chaining" multiple query operations...)

The strategy of this solution was:

1. To minimize the number of trips through one or more instances of this very large table.
2. To pre-process and index optimize any data that would otherwise be "static" for the duration of its analysis.
3. To audit and review the SQL code used to obtain the final results.

Definitely look into Access MACROS.  Coupled with identifying static data in your data sets, you can offload processing of your complex background analytic queries to improve the user experience when they view and query through the final results.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Richard for your help and constructive input. Unfortunately the subquery (SELECT TOP 10...) does not select the top 10 by group (in this case by ABCByPick), but only the top 10 from the table TempTableAnalysis. I would like to get the the best 10 MASE for ABCByPick = A, the best 10 MASE for ABCByPick = B, the best 10 MASE for ABCByPick = C etc.