# How to select the TOP 1 record per group (Partition)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I've got a table called **tblRoutes** that holds a unique list of from and to routes (f = from; t = to):

```
| fCity  | fState | tCity  | tState |
|========|========|========|========|
|New York|   NY   | Miami  |   CA   |
|Houston |   TX   |New York|   NY   |
...
```

And then I have a table called **tblCarrierRates** that lists a bunch of tiers and rates offered by carriers for travelling certain routes:

```
| fCity  | fState | tCity  | tState | Tier | Rate | CarrID |  CarrName   |
|========|========|========|========|======|======|========|=============|
|New York|   NY   | Miami  |   CA   |   2  | $2.99|  ABCD  | Abracadabra |
|New York|   NY   | Miami  |   CA   |   1  | $3.00|  BUMP  | Bumpy Rides |
|Houston |   TX   |New York|   NY   |   2  | $4.00|  SLOW  |Slow Carriers|
|Houston |   TX   |New York|   NY   |   2  | $4.01|  ABCD  | Abracadabra |
...
```

For each unique route listed in **tblRoutes** I'm looking for the 1 "best" offered from **tblCarrierRates**.

The criteria for "the best" is lowest *Tier*, followed by lowest *Rate*.

The result needs to return all the fields shown in **tblCarrierRates**, so based on the 2 routes shown above in **tblRoutes**, the desired result would be:

```
| fCity  | fState | tCity  | tState | Tier | Rate | CarrID |  CarrName   |
|========|========|========|========|======|======|========|=============|
|New York|   NY   | Miami  |   CA   |   1  | $3.00|  BUMP  | Bumpy Rides |
|Houston |   TX   |New York|   NY   |   2  | $4.00|  SLOW  |Slow Carriers|
```

The approach I was looking at was to sort in ascending order *Tier* and then *Rate*, then some how match the TOP 1 record for each unique combination of fCity, fState, tCity, and tState:

```
SELECT A.fCity, A.fState, A.tCity, A.tState, Q.Tier, Q.Rate, Q.CarrID, Q.CarrName
FROM tblRoutes As A LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 B.CarrID, B.CarrName, B.fCity, B.fState, B.tCity, B.tState, B.Rate, B.Tier
    FROM tblCarrierRates As B
    ORDER BY tblCarrierRates.Tier ASC, tblCarrierRates.Rate ASC) As Q
ON (A.tState = Q.tState) AND (A.tCity = Q.tCity) AND (A.fState = Q.fState) AND (A.fCity = Q.fCity);
```

The query doesn't fail, but as you can probably guess, the subquery I've written (Q) only returns a single record rather than 1 for each route in **tblRoutes**, so the end result is:

```
| fCity  | fState | tCity  | tState | Tier | Rate | CarrID |  CarrName   |
|========|========|========|========|======|======|========|=============|
|New York|   NY   | Miami  |   CA   |   1  | $3.00|  BUMP  | Bumpy Rides |
|Houston |   TX   |New York|   NY   |      |      |        |             |
```

...as you can see, nothing's been matched for Houston to New York because my sub query only returned 1 result rather than 1 for each route.

How can I achieve the result I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for an equivalent of the Sql Server and Oracle Analytic / Windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION .. ORDER BY)`, e.g. [like so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1c1a/2).

Although this isn't directly offered in MS Access, I believe it is possible to simulate a row numbering function in MS Access by applying a correlated subquery which counts the number of rows which have the same "Partition" (as defined by the join filter), and in which each row is ranked by counting the number of preceding rows in the same partition, which are 'below' the ordering criteria:

```
SELECT A.fCity, A.fState, A.tCity, A.tState, Q.Tier, Q.Rate, Q.CarrID, Q.CarrName, TheRank
FROM tblRoutes As A LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT B.CarrID, B.CarrName, B.fCity, B.fState, B.tCity, B.tState, B.Rate, B.Tier, 
      (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM  tblCarrierRates rnk 
        -- Partition Simulation (JOIN)
        WHERE B.fCity = rnk.fCity AND B.fState = rnk.fState 
              AND B.tCity = rnk.tCity AND B.tState = rnk.tState 
              -- ORDER BY Simulation
              AND (rnk.Tier < B.Tier OR 
                 (rnk.Tier = B.Tier AND rnk.Rate < B.Rate))) AS TheRank
      FROM tblCarrierRates As B) As Q
ON (A.tState = Q.tState) AND (A.tCity = Q.tCity) 
    AND (A.fState = Q.fState) AND (A.fCity = Q.fCity)
-- Now, you just want the top rank in each partition.
WHERE TheRank = 1;
```

Just be forewarned of performance - the subquery will be executed for each row.
Also, if there are ties, then both rows will be returned.

The +1 is to start each partition off with a Row number of 1 (since there will be zero preceding rows in its partition)

**Edit, taking out the comments**

```
SELECT A.fCity, A.fState, A.tCity, A.tState, Q.Tier, Q.Rate, Q.CarrID, Q.CarrName, TheRank
FROM tblRoutes As A LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT B.CarrID, B.CarrName, B.fCity, B.fState, B.tCity, B.tState, B.Rate, B.Tier, 
      (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM  tblCarrierRates rnk 
        WHERE B.fCity = rnk.fCity AND B.fState = rnk.fState 
              AND B.tCity = rnk.tCity AND B.tState = rnk.tState 
              AND (rnk.Tier < B.Tier OR 
                 (rnk.Tier = B.Tier AND rnk.Rate < B.Rate))) AS TheRank
      FROM tblCarrierRates As B) As Q
ON (A.tState = Q.tState) AND (A.tCity = Q.tCity) 
    AND (A.fState = Q.fState) AND (A.fCity = Q.fCity)
WHERE TheRank = 1
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after, but I'm getting "Syntax error in FROM clause". It's highlighting the line `FROM tblCarrierRates As B) As Q`

Comment: It seems Access doesn't like the comments I've added and breaks the query. I've repasted the exact working query I ran.

Comment: I'm only getting 1 result. I've taken off the `WHERE The Rank = 1` and it looks like it's not rank each unique combination of fCity, fState, tCity, and tState

Comment: Strange, I get two, exactly as per the SqlServer fiddle I posted - I used the data inserted in the fiddle, and the above query in MS Access

Comment: You're right, it does work. The tables and fields I posted were abbreviated versions of what I've actually got on my computer, so I was having to do a lot of find-and-replace on your query. I think somewhere I must have not converted it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Inner Query needs to group by city and state.  This will produce the 1 per city state that allows the outer join to join on those fields.

Debug your inner query independently until you see the results you would expect for your outer query to work.  Take out the Top1 at first so you can see that the sorting and grouping are working correctly.  I would explicitly put ASC DESC in your inner query so that others know which direction you intended the top to work against.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT fCity, fState, tCity, tState, MIN(Tier), MIN(Rate), CarrID, CarrName
FROM tblCarrierRates
GROUP BY fCity, fState, tCity, tState, CarrID, CarrName;
```

Comment: No, that won't produce the intended result.

Comment: I thinkn it should. though i haven't execute it, but it should be.

Comment: Yes, 2 `MIN`s won't work because they only focus on their own field independently

Comment: @GordThompson I'm looking at an answer you provided elsewhere on ranking... I'm trying to apply it, but I can't express the lowest Tier followed by lowest Rate effect I'm after: `A.LaneTier >= B.LaneTier AND A.Rate >= B.Rate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405074/ms-access-2010-sql-top-n-query-by-group-performance-issue-continued2